# How can I ignore a 'while-loop' if the Console.ReadLine() matches a defined input + only loops once when invalid input

Tags: c#, string, while-loop

I'm telling the user to key one of three possible colours. If the User incorrectly keys an colour (spelling etc...) - the 'while' function should repeat until they key a 'valid' colour.

The 'while' function seems to only run once and then just moves on regardless of what the user keys.

It also seems to disregard whatever the user keys first (even if it's correct) and enters the 'while' function. I obviously would like it to skip the 'while' function all together if the user selects correctly first time around.

*Edited the example due to some incorrect (OLD) code still being in there
Code example below...

```
Console.WriteLine("Select Colour (Red / Blue / Green): ");
string colSel = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

while (colSel != "Red" || colSel != "Blue" || colSel != "Green")

  {

   Console.WriteLine("Sorry, I didn't catch that...");
   Console.Write("Select Colour (Red / Blue / Green): ");
   colSel = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
   break;
  }

Console.WriteLine("Alright " + colSel + ", good. ");
```

Comment: Even better, use a `HashSet<string>` and add the three colours to it. Then use `!hashsetName.Contains(colSel)`. Then you don't have to worry about `||` vs `&&`.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few problems with the code:

**1. The `while` condition is always true**

```
while (colSel != "Red" || gClas != "Blue" || gClas != "Green")
```

The way the [`||` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#conditional-logical-or-operator-) (OR operator) works is that it evaluates each expression and returns `true` as soon as one of them evaluates to `true`. Since `colSel` cannot be more than one of the color strings, the condition will return `true` and the `while` loop will continue.

The operator you're looking for instead is the [`&&` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#conditional-logical-and-operator-) (AND operator), which returns `true` only if ALL the expressions return `true`, otherwise it returns `false`.

**2. You're calling `ToLower` on the input and comparing it to strings with upper-case characters**
So once again, none of the strings are going to match your comparisons. Using lower-case strings would be one way to handle this.

**3. There is a `break` statement inside the loop**
This means *"exit the loop immediately"*. It's counterpart is `continue` which means *"stop executing the current iteration and start the loop again"*. But you don't need either of these, since a `while` loop will automatically continue until the condition returns `false`.

So, to fix your code, you can do something like:

```
Console.Write("Select Colour (Red / Blue / Green): ");
string colSel = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

while (colSel != "red" && colSel != "blue" && colSel != "green")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sorry, I didn't catch that...");
    Console.Write("Select Colour (Red / Blue / Green): ");
    colSel = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
}

Console.WriteLine("Alright " + colSel + ", good. ");
```

---

Additionally, you can make the code a little easier to maintain (and improve the string comparison) by using an array (or list) of valid values that you compare the input to. This allows you to dynamically display the valid values (using `string.Join` on the array) and dynamically validate the input (by checking if `values.Contains` the input, using a case-insensitive comparer). But it may be a little advanced at this point.

To try it out, just add any strings you want to the array, and notice how the prompt changes and the validation handles the new addition automatically:

```
// Add any valid values to this array
var validValues = new[] {"Red", "Blue", "Green"};
var prompt = $"Select Colour ({string.Join(" / ", validValues)}): ";

Console.Write(prompt);
string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

while (!validValues.Contains(userInput, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Sorry, '{userInput}' is not a valid value.");
    Console.Write(prompt);
    userInput = Console.ReadLine();
}

Console.WriteLine("Alright " + userInput + ", good. ");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you comprehensive response. I'll take a look at your suggestions later and try and work out where I was going wrong!

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the loop only runs once (assuming the user keeps entering in the wrong input) is because it contains `break` at the end of the loop. `break` is a special keyword used to exit out of switch cases and loops.

On top of this, `colSel` gets set with a lower case version of the user's input, but the while loop comparison is using capitalization in the strings, meaning that correct user input will fail.

Try:

```
Console.WriteLine("Select Colour (Red / Blue / Green): ");
string colSel = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

// strings are now 'lowered'.
// also changed it so that all the variables look to colSel instead
while (colSel != "red" && colSel != "blue" && colSel != "green")
{

   Console.WriteLine("Sorry, I didn't catch that...");
   Console.Write("Select Colour (Red / Blue / Green): ");
   colSel = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
}

// Use string interpolation instead of concatenation
Console.WriteLine($"Alright {colSel}, good. ");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you response :) I'll try some of your suggestions later today